# Process entier DB to fetch data

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, teradata

Look at the query below. DB: ORACLE

```
select table_name, column_name, data_type from all_tab_cols 
where
data_type = 'DATE' and
OWNER = 'OWNER_NAME'
```

O/P:

```
TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE
T1         C1          DATE
T1         C2          DATE
T2         C3          DATE
T2         C4          DATE
```

Now, I got the result perfectly. I want to build up a query which processes further. From the result about, I want to pickup the table_name, column_name and apply a filter on column_name.

Example:

```
TABLE: T1
C1            c2
01-01-2001    01-01-2011
02-02-1990    05-05-1700
03-03-1753    10-10-1764
```

Like wise another Table...
Simply speaking, I want all the columns from DB where year of date field less than a particular year. I've tried but couldn't able to do it.

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do but it sounds like you need [dynamic sql](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it..

This query does it..

```
select table_name
      , column_name
      ,to_number(extractvalue(
       xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
       'select count(*) c from '||owner||'.'||table_name ||' WHERE extract(year from ' || column_name || ') < 1753'
       ))
       ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as count1

from all_tab_cols
where
data_type = 'DATE' and
OWNER = 'OWNER_NAME'
```